# Trying implement the plot function but its not displaying the graph

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

In this MATLAB code, I intend to display a graph, but it shows me an empty graph.

```
% Proposed Model For Two-Phase Flow Analytical Design Equation for gas
% pipelines
clc
d = 26.75; % diameter in inches 
pie = 3.142; %normal pie
A = (pie *d^2)/4; % Compute for the area
qm = 150; %volume flow rate of mixture
pm = 8; %Density of the mixture
Wm = qm* pm; % mass flow rate of mixture i.e oil and gas
Ho = 0.01; %Liquid Hold up
z = 0.85; % compressibility factor
R = 10.73; % Gas constant 
f = 0.0254; %friction factor
p0 = 150; % Density of oil
T = 580; % Temperature in R degrees
P0 =1700; % 1700psi
L = 63.068; % Length
P1 = 602.7; % 602.7 psia
%Assume
Mg = 9.8;

formule1 = d*A^2*Mg*(1-Ho);
formule2 = f*Wm^2*z*R*T;
formule = formule1/formule2;
exprs1 = (p0*Ho*z*R*T)/Mg*(1-Ho);
express2 = P2^2-P1^2
drop_p =P1-P2
express3 = 2*p0*Ho*z*R*T*drop_p
better_express = express2 + express3
func1 = d/f

solve( (formule*better_express)- func1*log(P2+ exprs1/P1 + exprs1)^2 + L == 0, P2)
figure
plot(drop_p,L,'r:+')
```

Please, can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code: `drop_p = P1-P2` and `L = 63.068`, so unless `P2` is a vector you will get just a single red + in your graph. Like this (for `P2 = 1`):

[image: red_cross]

Right now, the `solve` line returns an error, because it should be with `''` on the variable to solve to:

```
solve( (formule*better_express)- func1*log(P2+ exprs1/P1 + exprs1)^2 + L == 0, 'P2')
```

but this doesn't effect the resulted graph anyway, because the `solve` output is not assigned to any variable.